# Create dynamic equal sized small squares grid in fixed size big square

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, css-grid

How can I be able to create dynamic equal-sized squares inside a fixed big square? size should be according to number of squares.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code? What have you tried so far.

Comment: I haven't code yet as I wasn't able to get idea how to get proceed with code.

Comment: Is that what you mean? https://jsbin.com/yuwizas/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be the most universal solution. Using CSS `grid` whit countable column and rows, according to the sum of children element.

JS explanation:

1. `grid.children.length` - counts children of `grid` div.
2. `Math.sqrt(grid.children.length)` - returns the square root of a children length.
3. `Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(grid.children.length))` - rounds a number up to the next largest integer. So we get ours column and rows number.
4. `--cols` - set CSS variable to our `grid` elemetn.

This JavaScript works with any number of `grid` block.

```js
for (const grid of document.querySelectorAll('.grid')) {
  grid.style.setProperty('--cols', Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(grid.children.length)));
}
```

```css
.grid {
  --cols: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--cols), 1fr);
  column-gap: 2px;
  row-gap: 2px;
  background: #eee;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.grid>div {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```