# Best fit child divs to container (rows and columns)

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, css-grid

I'm trying to work out the best possible way to auto-size divs based on available space in the parent container to avoid a bunch of white space. I'm also hoping, that the solution should work regardless of how many divs exist (i.e - the amount can change over time).

It doesn't have to be a perfect fit and can use vertical scrolling, but I'm trying to avoid as much white space as possible. I played around with this script and it got me close, but I feel there's a better solution using css-grids auto-sizing capabilities:

```
if (size.width > size.height && divCount.length < 13) {
  columnSize = Math.round(12 / (divCount.length / 2));
}
if (size.width < size.height && divCount.length < 13) {
  columnSize = 6;
}
let colClass = 'col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-' + columnSize;
```

[image]
Starter File, I apologise for lack of code - I'm just really not sure where to even begin:
https://codepen.io/liamb/pen/KKVqvdz

Answer (score 0):

What about using flex, without js. For simplicity, I use tailwind:

```
<div class="flex h-screen flex-wrap">
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 h-full border bg-yellow-200 p-4">
      Div 1
    </div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 h-full border bg-yellow-200 p-4">
      Div 2
    </div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 h-full border bg-yellow-200 p-4">
      Div 3
    </div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 h-full border bg-yellow-200 p-4">
      Div 4
    </div>
</div>
```

See full example in the playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/vgzt2Lep/12/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the accurate desired result you wish to achieve. But have some ideas.

1. You can use class `.container-fluid` instead of `.container` for the full widht.
2. If you want the square shaped `col` - I made an example how to do it using `padding-top`

```css
.container-fluid{
  background: yellow;
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
.row{
  padding:15px;
  height: 100%;
}
.row > div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0;
}
.row > div::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100%;
} 
.row > div .col-in {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="col-in">
        Div 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="col-in">
        Div 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="col-in">
        Div 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="col-in">
        Div 4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is the example of using `grid-template-columns` and `auto-fill` and `auto-fit` (try to resize it for the best experience).

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}

hr {
  margin: 50px;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    /*just to resize the example, optional*/
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-container-fill {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.grid-container-fit {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.grid-element {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<h2>auto-fill</h2>
<div class="grid-container grid-container-fill">
  <div class="grid-element">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    7
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<h2>auto-fit</h2>
<div class="grid-container grid-container-fit">
  <div class="grid-element">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    7
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Although I have written an interesting [solution for a square shaped parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62374028/3187127).

---

If all the info above doesn't satisfies you - please, describe